# check If existing character in excel shape text vba

Tags: excel, vba, character, shapes

I would like to test if in the text of a shape, there is a text character, in this case it is a red check mark , which I add to the text of a button (shape) after a search. I attach the code where I add the check mark. Please can someone tell me how to know if it already exists.

```
Public Sub DisegnaSpunta(ByVal lngRow As Long, ByVal strNomeBottone As String)
     
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Dim strSpunta As String
      Dim rngSpunta As Range
      Dim testoBottone As String
      
      With ActiveSheet
          'Questo range serve solo per disegnare le righe sulla colonna G dove erano prima le spunte
           strSpunta = .Cells(lngRow, "G").Address
           Set rngSpunta = Range(strSpunta)
          
            testoBottone = .Shapes.Range(Array(strNomeBottone)).TextFrame.Characters.Text & " " & ChrW(&H2713)
            .Shapes.Range(Array(strNomeBottone)).TextFrame.Characters.Text = testoBottone
            .Shapes.Range(Array(strNomeBottone)).TextFrame.Characters(Start:=Len(testoBottone), Length:=1).Font.Color = vbRed
         CambiaBordiCella strSpunta
         
      End With
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
End Sub
```

Tanks a lot

Please can someone tell me how to know if it already exists?

Comment: A guess: you might consider using `Right` and `AscW`?

Comment: `If Right(.Shapes.Range(Array(strNomeBottone)).TextFrame.Characters.Text, 1) = ChrW(&H2713) Then`?